# Javascript validate on form Submit

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hi I want to validate the field values before submit the form here is my code

```
<table width="600" border="0" align="left">
<tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
function previewPrint()
{

var RegNumber = document.getElementById('PP_RegNoTextBox').value;
var PassportNo = document.getElementById('PP_PassportNoTextBox').value;
if (RegNumber=="")
{
    alert("Please enter your Reg No.!");
    document.getElementById('RegNoTextBox').focus();
    return false;
}
if (PassportNo=="")
{
    alert("Please enter your Passport No.!");
    document.getElementById('PassportNoTextBox').focus();
    return false;
}
    //window.open('regformview.php?RegNumber=RegNumber');
    }
    </script>
<form name="ppform" onSubmit="return previewPrint();" method="post" action="regformview.php">   
<td width="100" align="LEFT" class="font8">&nbsp; </td>
<td width="337" align="LEFT" class="font8"><u>Preview your Application:</u> Please provide requested details.<br>
  Reg No.: <input type="text" name="printregno" id="PP_RegNoTextBox" class="input2"> Passport No.:  <input type="text" name="printemail" class="input2"><input type="hidden" name="flagging" id="PP_PassportNoTextBox" value="1" class="input2">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="50" align="LEFT" class="font8"><div style="float:left; background-image:url(images/printPreview1.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;">   
  <input type="image" src="images/printPreview1.jpg" name="ppbutton" value="" onMouseOver="this.src='images/printPreview2.jpg'" onMouseOut="this.src='images/printPreview1.jpg'"></div></td>

</form>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Problem is its showing the alert box correctly if it blank but the page is navigating  to regformview.php after submitting. How to navigate to regformview.php only after validation.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are undefined:

```
document.getElementById('RegNoTextBox').focus();
document.getElementById('PassportNoTextBox').focus();
```

it should be:

```
document.getElementById('PP_RegNoTextBox').focus();
document.getElementById('PP_PassportNoTextBox').focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine, except you have error in your script with let you submit even if validation fails.

**change the following lines**

```
 document.getElementById('PassportNoTextBox').focus();
```

and

```
document.getElementById('RegNoTextBox').focus();
```

**as**

```
 document.getElementById('PP_PassportNoTextBox').focus();
```

and

```
 document.getElementById('PP_RegNoTextBox').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it should work.

```
onSubmit="previewPrint();return false;"
```

Comment: Using that, the form will never submit. Unless you want some very frustrated users (and no form submissions), I wouldn't recommend that.